# Error while creating react-native app in linux

Tags: linux, reactjs, react-native, linux-kernel

I have installed node and checked it as the node js docs suggested by doing `node -v` and `npm version`  and I got the same expected results as they showed in the docs

But I couldnt run **`npm install -g react-native-cli`**
This is the error that I get :
[image: This is the error that I get]

Comment: You need to either use sudo before that command or chmod your /usr/lib/node_modules

Comment: man that worked u could have commented this as answer

Comment: Bojan Ivanac said the same thing as I said, validate their answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
sudo chmod +rwx /usr/lib/node_modules
```

Or run your npm install as `sudo` but that's never a good idea.